# Banners inside MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, banner-ads

I am looking to add banners to the bottom of every page in a MediaWiki-powered wiki so that when a user loads or refreshes a page, a random ad banner advertising an external website  shows up in the footer of said page. I cannot find an extension that does this, so is there a different way to implement the banners?

Answer (score 3):

You don't mention what skin you're using but Vector is the default skin on current installs. The simplest way is to include your ad code below the `<!-- /bodyContent -->` tag in the skin file `/skins/Vector.php`. The most comprehensive extension to accomplish this that I have found is [PCR GUI Inserts](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aPCR_GUI_Inserts).